# Pass data from one activity to another and set to particular EditText field from which it is called

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Activity1 contains multiple edittext and buttons, Activity2 contains 1 edittext and button. Activity1 calls Activity2 on button click. In activity2, if u set a value to edittext and click the btn set that value to activity1 field from which it is called

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onNav"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onNav"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onNav"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/OK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:onClick="onNavBack"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onNav(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }
    public void onNavBack(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Expected o/p:
if I click button, navigate to activity2, by clicking the btn OK it should set the text to editText. Similarly if I click button2, after clicking OK it should set the text to editText2.

Comment: So what is the issue? Have a dig a google?

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
String value="Hello world";

    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
    i.putExtra("key",value);
    startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```